# MVC 3 Getting error when passing data from controller to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm getting this error.

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`3[ACapture.Models.Blog,ACapture.Models.Image,ACapture.Models.Profile]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ACapture.Models.Blog]'.

Here's my controller.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private ACaptureDB db = new ACaptureDB();

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "ArchiCapture";
        var dateCheck = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);

        var results = (from r in db.Blog
                      join p in db.Image on r.ImageID equals p.ImageID
                      //join l in db.Account on p.AccountID equals l.AccountID
                      join a in db.Profile on p.AccountID equals a.AccountID
                      //where r.dte_created >= dateCheck
                       select new { r, p, a });

        return View(results);
    }
```

Here's my view.

```
@model IEnumerable<ACapture.Models.Blog>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="Forum">
    <p>The Forum</p>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <div class="ForumChild">
                    <img src="@item.Image.img_path" alt="Not Found" />
                    <br />
                        <table>
                            @foreach (var comment in item.comment)
                            {
                                var db = new ACapture.Models.ACaptureDB();

                                var Name = from p in db.Profile
                                           where (p.AccountID == comment.AccountID)
                                           select new { p.FirstName, p.LastName };


                                <tr><td></td><td>@comment.Commentation</td></tr>
                            }
                        </table>
                </div>                
            }
</div>
```

The error occurs whenever the data is passed from the controller to the view.

**Also I need the data from all three tables Blog, Image, and Profile**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your View is expecting an IEnumerable of ACapture.Models.Blog.  However, your query and join are return a new {Blog, Image, Profile}.  Just like when you do a join in SQL and don't specify the columns, you get them all back.  This creates an anonymous type.  You just want to select{r} for Blog

Comment: what if I need the data from the other 2 tables (Profile and Image) as well?

Comment: @dright...you would need to create a Model object that represents the data from all 3 tables.

Comment: @Dright....also,if you set up your Model structure as parent/child relationships, EF will give you back a list of blogs pointing to the images, pointing to the profiles.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing `IEnumerable<anonymous type>` as model, while view expects `IEnumerable<ACapture.Models.Blog>`. Try

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "ArchiCapture";
    var dateCheck = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);

    var results = (from r in db.Blog
                  join p in db.Image on r.ImageID equals p.ImageID
                  //join l in db.Account on p.AccountID equals l.AccountID
                  join a in db.Profile on p.AccountID equals a.AccountID
                  //where r.dte_created >= dateCheck
                   select r);

    return View(results);
}
```

Comment: What if I need the data from the Image and Profile table ?

Comment: Then you have to create a specialized viewmodel containing them, and select into it.

Answer (score 2):

You're using projection to create an anonymous type. Your view is expecting an IEnumerable. Try to select new Blog { }

Comment: Like this ? select new Blog { r, p, a } );     It says cannot initialize type 'ACapture.Models.Blog' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable

Comment: Call ToList() on it. In your view just make your model List<Blog>